# Online - Opening documents in client application keep asking for credentials

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-editor-web-part

I've made a CEWP using REST API and Javascript where I create some links to documents that are stored in a document library. These documents must open in the client application (eg: Word) and not in the browser.

The default behaviour set in the document library is to open document in the client application.

This is the code to generate the link (found here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/231055/20605):

```
var linkDoc = "ms-word:ofe|u|https://contoso.sharepoint.com" + data.d.results[i].FileRef;
```

I've tried to put my SharePoint Online URL in Intranet Sites (Internet Options), but when the document is opened in my client application (Word 2016) it keeps to asking me credentials.

Is there a way to stop asking credentials? If is a problem of the link, is there an alternative way to open document in client application?

Answer (score 2):

Does this only happen when you are using the CEWP / REST API?

I don't know if Internet Options are the cause of your issue, but I thought I'd  show my settings in case you it would be helpful to rule at this as being an issue.  Here is what I have for my internet options/Security/**Custom Level**.  There are three 'tabs' (one for Internet, one Local Internet and one for Trusted Sites.

[image: internet options]

So on the Internet Tab & Trusted Sites have one setting for me.  Local Intranet is different.  See pictures below.

[image: Custom Level]

[image: User Authentication Settings]

Comment: I've selected the option "Automatic logon only in Intranet zone". When I open the document from the document library it opens in the client application but it keeps asking me credentials. The document is in .docm format